# How can I recreate this custom image download feature?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, download, portfolio

A friend of mine has this feature on their site that I'm looking to recreate.
A URL is sent to the recipient, who can select the images they want and download them easily.

What would be the easiest way to recreate this?

https://ofafashion.co.uk/albums/p0Tu4b/digigirls-instagramready/8bf9b327314b89417af7798774a4bebcd1881b0f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an `useState` storing the selected images ids and a function to download those images in an archive (using, for example, [jszip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip))